# JSONP in Javascript: remove script DOM element immediately

Tags: javascript, dom, jsonp

There is something I don't understand in the DOM/Javascript flow in the following classical function which builds a script DOM element dynamically in order to have a JSONP request served within this injected script:

```
function requestServerCall(url) { //Construct the script tag at Runtime  
  var head = document.head;  
  var script = document.createElement("script");  
  script.setAttribute("src", url);  
  head.appendChild(script);  
  head.removeChild(script); // remove the script tag once inserted to avoid memory consumption  
}
```

What I don't get is: this function immediately removes the script child from the DOM. Does it means the function hangs *when* appending the child? I think not. So it means the DOM will sort of *remember* to remove the child *after* the insertion of it has been fulfilled through the HTTP request of the injected url.

Intuitively, I would think this is the call-back's job (call-back embedded in the url in this example) to destroy the script (or a timer call-back as we have no guarantee call back will be ever called in case of failure).

Can someone elaborate on the Javascript/DOM execution flow which justifies this 'early' child removal in the DOM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the `script` element to the DOM immediately tells the browser to fetch the script and, once it's fetched, execute it. `appendChild` does not block while that happens.

The browser doesn't "remember" to do the `removeChild` later, it does it right away. But removing the `script` element from the DOM does nothing to stop the process of fetching and running the script; it's already been started.

So adding and removing right away is fine.

Being a bit paranoid, I'd always test on my target browsers, just in case of implementation oddities.

Comment: Thank you. This fully answers my question and the last remark is useful: some browsers may behave a little differently and we must be cautious...

Comment: So I tried to think a little bit more deeply how this works actually. It seems to me the 'script' element we create in JS would be garbage collected by the DOM (or whatever manages it) after the removeChild call. However, the http request it involves, including the call-back action it embeds in the answer content will execute, maintaining a reference to this element, and only after the call-back completion, will this last reference be removed, enabling the garbage collector to act on the element. Luckily...

Comment: @Djee: Certainly the code loading the script and executing it will have a reference to the `script` element (so the `load` or `error` events can be fired), but I don't think that's why things keep going. I think by the time `removeChild` is called, the browser's already committed to loading and running the script, the `script` element is just along for the ride.